# how to monitor cpu usage and network usage during a performece test

Tags: linux, performance, testing, cpu-usage

I need to run performence testing of an application(written in c++) under **linux** enviroment, how can I monitor the cpu usage, network card usage and memory usage during the test?

Answer (score 5):

If no GUI installed on Linux server, try some of the following commands to start with:

1. **top/htop** displays CPU usage, Memory usage, Swap Memory, PID, User, Commands and much more.
2. **iostat** shows system input and output storage device statistics, etc.
3. **netstat** monitors incoming and outgoing network packets statistics as well as interface statistics.
4. **lsof** displays list of all the open files and the processes.
5. **vmstat** displays statistics of virtual memory, kernel threads, disks, system processes, I/O blocks, interrupts, CPU activity, ...

Answer (score 0):

Try gnome-system-monitor
This will give you graphic representation of each.